# Android failing to connect to MySQL database properly

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-networking

I'm trying to get the basics of an Android app that sends and receives data from a MySQL server (my implementation will have nothing to do with this learning example). Here's the code so far:

```
package com.davekelley.polling;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Chart extends Activity {

    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chartfragment);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.davidjkelley.net/city.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            String line="0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        //paring data
        int ct_id;
        String ct_name;
        try{
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ct_id=json_data.getInt("CITY_ID");
                ct_name=json_data.getString("CITY_NAME");
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the XML file 'chartfragment':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<!-- <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chartTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:gravity="center"/>
-->

    </ListView>
```

And here are the LogCat problems I'm encountering:

```
03-26 20:34:13.782: E/log_tag(1025): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-26 20:34:13.802: E/log_tag(1025): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 20:34:13.802: D/AndroidRuntime(1025): Shutting down VM
03-26 20:34:13.802: W/dalvikvm(1025): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.davekelley.polling/com.davekelley.polling.Chart}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.davekelley.polling.Chart.onCreate(Chart.java:68)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-26 20:34:13.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     ... 11 more
```

So obviously the network connection on main thread problem means I need to move this into an Asynctask, right? But with such a bevy of errors, I wonder if I am missing something else, that's obvious? I eventually want to be able to register user/passwords onto a database, then get queries and send responses, so this is just a warm up basically. If you goto http://www.davidjkelley.net/city.php you can see that the database is indeed properly responding to the query PHP file that I have linked inside the Android code, so that's not the problem.

Edit~ I should note that my Activity previously extended list Activity, following this tutorial: http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/ which is why my XML is just a ListView at the moment, because that helped clear up an error that said I needed a ListView component with the id 'list'.

Edit~ My php code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","***","***");
mysql_select_db("***");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from CITY where CITY_NAME like 'A%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Obviously the sets of stars are the correct information, as when you visited the link posted above, the SQL readout appears properly.

Comment: If you're getting NetworkOnMainThreadException that's as fundamental as it gets.  Fix that first.  The fact you're hitting a .php page with mysql DB is a side issue at this point.  You probably haven't even sent a SYN packet...

Comment: Would you care to elucidate? I asked about how to create an Asynctask for this as well...

Comment: For async this looks like one place to start:  http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html  in particular see section 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are your running your database? Posting how the PHP connects may be more relevant. It's very possible that in the PHP you aren't connecting the request from the app to the actual database (either with an incorrect url or the name of the database itself). Check out [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) tutorial. I can confirm it works fine and it seems to accomplish the functionality you need as well. In that tutorial there are notes on where to change the code so that you can run it on your hosted server instead of localhost.

Comment: Also, thank you for the link. I will be using that once I've got this basic aspect under my belt!

Comment: KDEx, just wanted to let you know that I recreated that tutorial almost letter for letter with copy paste. The only thing I changed was the local host IP address to my actual server online. I end up with the same error I'm dealing with in my original question, NetworkOnMainThreadException. Any advice?

Comment: @Davek804 Who are your using to host? I ran into a similar error (and the reason I mentioned php) because you can't just connect it to `davidkjelly.net/city/`. In my case since I use godaddy I needed to connect instead to `mydatabasename.db.idnumber.hostedresource.com`

Comment: NameCheap. I will look into that, do you know the way to find the proper URL via CPanel? When I FTP in, I don't seem to have anything in terms of filestructure for the db.

Comment: @Davek804 for godaddy I need to log into where I created the database and go into the configuration panel. NameCheap should have something similar

Comment: So it looks like I am correcting to the database properly. There is a user prefix with an underscore prior to the dB name, but I already had that. It looks like I am connecting properly because when I run the city.php script on a webpage, it prints out the data from within the table.

Comment: All working. I hate to admit it, but I get the feeling that I by mistake added a line somewhere in UserFunctions, because when I re-copy/pasted from the tutorial (and updated my URLs again) it worked justtttt fine. Grats on the solution :)