# Can individual methods implement Asynctask?

Tags: php, android, sql

Even if the class they reside in doesn't implement it?

Comment: Java does not have methods as first class objects - it's not C#. So no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Nor can the containing class *implement* `AsyncTask`.  `AsyncTask` is an abstract superclass, not an interface, so you *extend* it rather than *implement* it.

But regardless, a method cannot extend a class or implement an interface.  However, you might be able to use an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) to provide an `AsyncTask` implementation that just calls your method at the appropriate place.

Comment: Mmm, wrong keyword - thanks. So how do I go about querying an SQL server from onCreate as this tutorial shows: http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/ (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879448/android-failing-to-connect-to-mysql-database-properly)